# ARCore: AR Views Differences and Clarification

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

What's the difference between [**ArSceneView**](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ArSceneView), [**ArFragment**](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ArFragment), and [**ScenView**](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/SceneView)? I've seen all of these being used in Google's examples for ArCore but I don't understand the difference between them and the interchanging of them in different applications. The websites for each don't provide much information and aren't helpful to a beginner. What general properties are different between these? What should be used when?

Thanks!